# defining explicit overloaded constructor issue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have following class that some of the operators are overloaded:

```
class CLASS1
{
       CLASS1();
       CLASS1(const CLASS1 &obj);

   CLASS1 operator +(const CLASS1 &obj) {
       CLASS1 srcObj;
       // doing add stuff here
           return srcObj;
       }

   void func()
   {
   CLASS1 boj = // some method which returns CLASS1 obj.
   }


   CLASS1& operator =(const CLASS1 &obj) {
       // copy properties
       }
}
```

Ok, this works fine. but after awhile I decided to make my class explicit to avoid implicit conversions. Therefore, I've made it this way:

```
class CLASS1
{
       explicit CLASS1();
       explicit CLASS1(const CLASS1 &obj);

   CLASS1 operator +(const CLASS1 &obj) {
       CLASS1 srcObj;
       // doing add stuff here
           return srcObj;          // compiler gives non-matching errors
   }

   void func() {
       CLASS1 boj = somemethods(); // compiler gives non-matching errors
   }

   CLASS1& operator =(const CLASS1 &obj) {
       // copy properties
       }
}
```

Now, the compiler gives 'no matching function to call...' error (specified in the code above), in spite of I've explicitly overloaded assignment operator. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return an object by value the copy-constructor is called *implicitly*. If you say it's not allowed to be called implicitly you will get an error.

You should not use `explicit` for your default, copy or move constructors. Or for constructors taking more than one argument. Only for constructors taking a single argument (with the noted exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, when returning an object from a method, an object you receive outside method call is actually a copy of an object you declare inside method. So compiler must have a permitted way to "transfer contents" from in-method object to method result. Since in-method instance is no longer needed, the move is the best approach (yes, you need to add move constructor):

```
CLASS1(CLASS1&& obj);
```

This will allow you to forbid implicit conversions, while maintaining the ability to have temporary objects.

In real life, the afforementioned copy/move will likely be optimized away by RVO/NRVO.